# What is the -t used for in this Perl code

Tags: perl, filehandle

I read in the perldoc that the -t file operator is used to decide if a filehandle is opened to a tty or not. Then i read what a tty was and from what i understand it's an old term for a terminal?

My main question however is what this code is used for:

```
if(-t STDERR) {
    die "some warning/error message here"
}
```

I guess i don't really understand what it means for a "filehandle to be opened to a tty". Does that mean that the particular output for that filehandle appears on the tty - or the terminal? Can tty refer to something besides the terminal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This code wants to assert that standard error is being redirected to a file. So running

```
perl the_script.pl
```

would trigger the `die` call, but

```
perl the_script.pl 2> error.log
```

would not.

Answer (score 7):

TTYs are a type of unix device. Consoles appear as TTYs to programs, so that statement basically reads as

"If STDERR is sent to a console, ..."

But not quite. We're not talking about physical devices but logical devices such as `/dev/tty*`. As such, it's possible for a program to pretend to be a terminal. For example, [Expect](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?Expect) uses [IO::Pty](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?IO::Pty) to do this.

STDERR could also be a plain file, a pipe or a socket. `-t` would be false for these.

```
script 2>foo        # Plain file
script 2>&1 | cat   # Pipe
```