# -t in the body of a perl script

Tags: perl, tty

I have a script with a line like this:

```
$foo = $bar if -t;
```

Near as I can tell, this is saying,

1. if this script is run from a terminal, set `$foo` to `$bar`.
2. If this script was run from cron, that would evaluate to false.

Have I got this right?

Comment: Always read the perldoc (https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X) before asking questions.

Comment: I'm asking for clarification on the documentation.

Comment: @Lucky Then maybe you should mention that you want a clarification on the documentation.

Comment: The documentation is pretty clear, and you could always write a 3-line script and run it from cron to see what happens.  That would likely answer your question faster than posting here.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20332218/what-is-the-t-used-for-in-this-perl-code

Answer (score 3):

In perldoc perlfunc for the collection of functions called [`-X`](https://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X), you can read:

```
-t  Filehandle is opened to a tty.
```

Also

```
If the argument is omitted, tests $_, except for -t, which tests STDIN.
```

Which is to say your code does `-t STDIN`.

Comment: So its asking if the script if its having input piped to it?

Comment: @Lucky When I am testing it, it returns true if STDIN is not active, and if I am piping input to perl it returns false.

Comment: @Lucky If I were to guess, someone might be trying to find out whether the program is reading from STDIN or from ARGV? The context might give you some clues, what is the $foo and $bar variables doing?

Comment: @Lucky Re "*So its asking if the script if its having input piped to it?*", No. Plain files, sockets and non-TTY devices also aren't TTYs.

Answer (score 1):

The `-t` file test is documented in [perlfunc](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlfunc#-X), although you get to by looking up `-X` instead of the specific file test:

```
% perldoc -f -X
```

Depending on your task, [IO::Interactive](https://metacpan.org/pod/IO::Interactive) may do the job better since there can be a few gotchas with figuring out if something is truly interactive.

If you want to know that you are running under cron (and not non-interactive in some other way), you might consider have a variable set in your crontab (or using one already set) and simply looking for it. In your crontab:

```
IN_CRON=1
```

Then, in the script:

```
do_something() if $ENV{IN_CRON};
```